# Expanding search goto a url on form submit with field values added to the url string

Tags: jquery, forms, url

I am trying to get an expanding search to add the value of the search input and go to a specific URL on submit if value exist in search field. I am unable ot get it to work.

The example code i am using is from this codepen.

http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var searchbox=$('.searchbox-input').val();
var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
var isOpen = false;
submitIcon.click(function () {
    if (isOpen == false) {
        searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
        inputBox.focus();
        isOpen = true;
        location.href = "/search.aspx?q=" + searchbox;
    } else {
        searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
        inputBox.focusout();
        isOpen = false;

    }

});
submitIcon.mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});
searchBox.mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    if (isOpen == true) {
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
        submitIcon.click();
    } });
});
function buttonUp() {
var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
if (inputVal !== 0) {
    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('.searchbox-input').val('');
    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
}
```

}

and the HTML is

```
<form class="searchbox">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
            <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value="GO">
            <span class="searchbox-icon">GO</span>
        </form>
```

Comment: So by saying _I am unable ot get it to work_ what do you mean? do you get any errors or what? and also you have this line `location.href = "/search.aspx?q=" + searchbox;` which will redirect your page every time user click on the `GO`. I know that at least this line will cause you some problems. But if you have other issues with your code, please elaborate on _I am unable ot get it to work_

Comment: Sorry that is what is happening rather than on click if there is a value entered in the field.

Comment: You have to use the `.submit()` function to capture the `submit event` of the form and check if the `search input` is not empty, then use this line:`location.href = "/search.aspx?q=" + searchbox;`. if it's what you are looking for, I can pose a sample answer for you

Comment: That would be awesome if you could using my javascript and code. I am so lost on this one. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I still am not sure what you have in mind, I think This will do, if not please tell me which behavior of this code is not what you expect?

here is the complete JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
    var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
    var submitButton = $('.searchbox-submit');
    var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
    var isOpen = false;

    submitIcon.click(function(){
        if(isOpen == false){
            searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focus();
            isOpen = true;
        }
        else{
            searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focusout();
            isOpen = false;
        }
    });

    submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });

    searchBox.mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        if(isOpen == true){
            $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
            submitIcon.click();
        }
    });

    // This function has beed added
    submitButton.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
        if($.trim(inputVal).length !== 0){
          location.href = "/search.aspx?q="+inputVal;
        }
    }); 
});

function buttonUp(){
    var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
    inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;

    if (inputVal !== 0) {
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        $('.searchbox-input').val('');
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

also added two `name` and `id` attributes to the `form` tag and your html code will look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="searchbox">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
        <button class="searchbox-submit">GO</button>
        <span class="searchbox-icon">GO</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error is 

3test2.html:144 Uncaught ReferenceError: searchbox is not defined(anonymous function) @ test2.html:144m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: oh one quick issue. I can not have it in a form tag. The form has to live in a div. Any way to have it use a div rather than a form?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I edited the post and corrected the variable name. actually the correct variable name is `inputVal ` not `searchbox`

Comment: it does not matter if the `form` is inside a `div` or not. you have to have your input inside a `form` otherwise you have to capture `Enter key press` manually which is not logical. just let the `form` be there.

Comment: It is because i have to use this in a asp.net page that has a form tag around the whole page. Real pain in butt. :)

Comment: Also i fixed the error. It was the var name and i modified it to this but seems to not work on mouseup

// This function has beed added
    submitIcon.mouseup(function(event){
        //event.preventDefault();
        var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
        if($.trim(inputVal).length !== 0){
          location.href = "/search.aspx?q="+inputVal;
        }
    });

Comment: OK, in that case if you can not use `form`, I've just modified the code and bind the event to the submit button element. and then you can add the Enter key press event to the code afterward. I also modified the `HTML` and removed the `form` and replaced it with a `div`. also replaced the submit button with a `button element`. Please give it a try.

Comment: I have setup a fiddle for it but it does not appear to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/hrfoyue1/1/

Thank you so much for the help on this!

Comment: wait i hade to set the fiddle to not wrap the js. Works!!!! Thank you soooo much!!!! :)